# cog task for discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

This is supposed to send a message in the channel every 15 minutes.
For some reason, it's not working. It doesn't show any error either. Can someone help me fix this?

```
import time

from discord.ext import commands

message = 'choose roles from <#728984187041742888>'
channel_id = 742227160944869437  # the channel id (right click on the channel to get it)
time_spacing = 15*60  # s : 15min


class auto(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def spamm(self, ctx):
        while True:
            time.sleep(time_spacing)
            await ctx.get_channel(channel_id).send(message)


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Sp4mm3r {self.bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
        print('Sending message :', message, 'every', time_spacing, 'seconds')


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(auto(bot))
```

----------corrected version-----------
figured the issue was that i didn't start the task, and time.sleep wasn't meant to be used there.

```
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext import commands


time = 30*60


class Automessager(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message = 'Choose roles from <#728984187041742888>'
        self.channel1 = 725550664561983519
        self.text.start()
  

    @tasks.loop(seconds=time)
    async def text(self):
        try:
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel1)
            await channel.send(self.message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'{self.bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
        print(f'Sending message: {self.message} every {time} seconds')


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Automessager(bot))
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the corrected version!

Answer (score 1):

There's two errors in your code:

- `get_channel()` is a [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) method, not a [`discord.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context) method.
- If you use `time.sleep()` to wait 15 minutes, it will freeze your entire cog.

To make loops, you can use [`task.loop()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task#discord.ext.tasks.loop), instead of using cog listeners:

```py
from discord.ext import task
from discord.ext import commands


class auto(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message = 'Choose roles from <#728984187041742888>'
        self.channel_id = 742227160944869437
        self.minutes = 15

    @task.loop(minutes=self.minutes)
    async def spamm(self, ctx):
         channel = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel_id)
         await channel.send(self.message)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Sp4mm3r {self.bot.user} has connected to Discord!')
        print(f'Sending message: {self.message} every {self.minutes} minutes')


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(auto(bot))
```

PS: I've set `channel_id`, `message` and `minutes` as class variables. You also don't need to use `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Thnx dude! I didn't know the correct usage of time.sleep. it still wasn't working. Issue was I forgot to start the task